# Using multiple Heroku logging add-ons simultaneously

Tags: heroku, logentries, papertrail-app

Is it ok to simultaneously use both Papertrail and LogEntries logging with the same Heroku application, or could that cause issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: there shouldn't be any issue. As stated in the [logplex documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logplex), there can be as many log-drains as you want, starting just from the CLI, going over to custom log-drains, and addons as you wish.